# When is the prefix ne- and when is it mal-?

Tags: affixes, adjectives

The meanings of adjectives can be altered by adding a prefix. Most people know that *mal-* makes opposites, but the meaning of *ne-* is a bit more vague. How should I know when to use *ne-* instead of *mal-*?

Some of them I just know by experience. The only *ne*-word I can think of right now is *nekredebla*. Examples with *mal-* are *malsana*, *malforta* and *malgaja*.

Here are some of the adjectives I am wondering about:

*necesa, utila, interesa, grava, certa, klara, kontenta, kapabla, simila, sama*

Comment: Can `nevera` describe things that aren't coherent enough to be true or false?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To your list of prefixes, you could add ***sen***-.

If something has a clear opposite, then it's *mal-* (e.g. *malvera, malsimila, malsama*).

If it's something that is either there or not, then it's *-ne* (e.g. *nenecesa*).

If the quality is lacking, then it's *sen-* (e.g. *senutila*).

Most of the words you listed can go more than one way. For example:

- *neinteresa*
- *seninteresa*
- *malinteresa*

Of the three, *malinteresa* is the least interesting.

Comment: You mean **ne-**, not **-ne**, I guess.

Comment: Correct. It should be ne- -- a prefix.

Answer (score 15):

The meaning of *ne* is not really vague: It is just negation. You can use either to express what you mean, but in some cases the opposite and negation coincide: For instance with *vera*; *nevera* and *malvera* are the same, because anything that is ‘not true’ is ‘false’. In these cases I think *mal* might be preferred. (In this case I found only 2 instances of `\bnever[aeiou](s)?\b` and 90 of `\bmalver[aeiou](s)?\b` in tekstaro.)

*Malnecesa* is something like ‘superfluous’, while *nenecesa* is just ‘not necessary’, which need not be superfluous, but just not required.
Further examples, *malutila* would be something like ‘detrimental’, while *neutila* is just ‘useless’. *Neklara* is unclear, while *malklara* is vague. Again, *nesama* and *malsama* coincide, because the opposite of ‘being the same’ is ‘being different’, which is ‘not being the same’.

Answer (score 2):

Some words don't have opposites. People often think of invisible (nevidebla) as the opposite of visible (videbla) but it isn't. It's either see-able or it's not.

Answer (score 2):

There is no a general rule, but you can get it by logic.

- Sometimes, *mal-* and *ne-* may be used to achive the same meaning, e.g.:

  **mal/kontenta**, **ne/kontenta**: *Deziranta ion alian ol tion, kion oni havas* ([PIV](http://vortaro.net/#malkontenta))
- Other times, the difference could be a subtle nuance:

  **ne/certa**: *Duba* [(PIV)](http://vortaro.net/#necerta)
  **mal/certa**: *Tute ne certa* [(PIV)](http://vortaro.net/#malcerta)

  **ne/klara**: *Konfuza, nedistingebla* [(PIV)](http://vortaro.net/#neklara)
  **mal/klara**: *Ne tute klara* [(PIV)](http://vortaro.net/#malklara)
- Other times, the meaning may be remarkably different:

  **ne/utila**: (= sen/utila) *Tia, ke ĝi donas nenian utilon*  ([PIV](http://vortaro.net/#neutila))
  **mal/utila**: *Tia, ke ĝia uzo, efiko, rezulto alportas aŭ povas alporti malbonon, difekton, malprofiton* ([PIV](http://vortaro.net/#malutila))

Pomego has a paragraph about [the difference between *mal* and *ne*](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/prefiksoj/mal.html#i-ctc).

Answer (score 1):

Ne = no or not

Mal = opposite

**Blanka**:

- White = blanka - The house is white
- Not white = neblanka - The house is not white
- Black = malblanka - The house is black

**Utila**:

- Useful = utila
- Not useful = neutila
- A hindrance (the opposite of useful) = malutila

**Note:**

In English, we can say "He is unhealthy" or "He is sick". Both have different meanings although they are similar. There are many cases where it doesn't make sense to use Mal- because there is no opposite. For example, I can't say Malauxto, but I can say Malforta.

Comment: "malblanka" does not mean "black".  Colors do not have "logical opposites".

Comment: @Lee being a logical language and since a color wheel exists, couldn't it work out given mal[color] isn't a word that means something else?