# Kio estas la diferenco inter "mallibera" kaj "nelibera"?

Tags: word-difference

Mi scias, ke ja estas diferenco inter "nebona" kaj "malbona", ĉar io povas ne esti bona sed sen esti tute malbona, t.e. per esti "neŭtra".

Tamen mi kredas, ke io "mallibera" necese estas io ne libera, ĉar ne ekzistas "mezo" inter libereco kaj mallibereco. Ĉu ne?

Do, kio estas la diferenco inter "mallibera" kaj "nelibera"? Ĉu ili estas sinonimoj?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Tri bildoj: Hundo kuras sur plaĝo; hundo promenas per ŝnuro; hundo kuŝas en kaĝo]

En la unua foto, la hundo kuras *libere* sur la plaĝo.

En la dua foto, la hundo promenas, sed *ne libere*, pro la ŝnuro.

En la tria foto, la hundo kuŝas, *mallibera* en la kaĝo.

La prefikso *mal-* specifas la malon, la plej kutiman kontraŭkoncepton aŭ inverson.

Kompreneble, eblas diskuti (kaj disputi) la naturon kaj gradojn de libereco, laŭ la situacio, ĉar eĉ la hundo en la unua foto devas obei sian posedanton; tamen, mi esperas ke la diferenco inter la aliaj situacioj estas sufiĉe klara: la dua hundo povas moviĝi de loko al loko en limigata maniero, kaj povas esprimi inklinojn kaj tuj influi sian posedanton, tiel ke certaj liberecoj ankoraŭ ekzistas; sed la tria hundo nur povas moviĝi surloke kaj plejparte oni atentas nur ĝiajn bazajn bezonojn, tiel ke nur la plej malgrandaj liberecoj ankoraŭ ekzistas.

Comment: Vi pravas ke eblas diskuti kaj disputi. Oni ja povas diri ke la ŝnuro malliberigas la dua hundon, kaj ke la tria hundo ne kuŝas libera. Ja temas pri diferenco de emfazo.

Comment: Mi tre sxatas la foto.  Mi volas rimarki ke en la tria foto, la hundo estas nelibera kaj mallibera, sed nur nelibera en la dua foto.  Ili estas sinonimoj, sed ne kompletaj sinonimoj.

Comment: @Karlomanio -  Efektive, kaj en la dua foto kaj en la trio la hundo estas kaj mallibera kaj ne libera. Andrew diris (prave) ke la hundo promenas sed **ne libere**. Li ne diris ke la hundo **ne** estas **mallibera**.

Answer (score 0):

Ĉu vi jam legis la respondon [tie ĉi](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/when-is-the-prefix-ne-and-when-is-it-mal)?

Mi rekomendas ne uzi la vorton "nelibera". Diru aŭ "ne libera" aŭ "mallibera". Ili ne estas sinonimoj. Temas pri diferenco de emfazo.

Comment: Kio estas tiu "diferenco de emfazo"?

Comment: Mi kredas ke oni jam bone klarigis tion [tie ĉi](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/when-is-the-prefix-ne-and-when-is-it-mal). Ĉu vi jam legis tiun respondon? Oni vidas la saman aferon en la naciaj lingvoj. Ĉu via denaska lingvo ne havas esprimojn similajn al "mallibera" kaj "ne libera"?

Comment: Esperanto Stack Exchange estus pli bona loko se pli da homoj havus kuragxon komenti por plibonigi respondojn anstataux nur doni minusan vocxdonon.

Comment: En la franca, mia denaska lingvo, estas la vorto "kaptita". Ĉu ĝi estas sinonimo de "mallibera"?

Comment: Nu "sinonimo" dependas de via kompreno de tiu vorto. La signifoj estas similaj kun diferencoj. Mi povas imagi, ekzemple, ke iu povus diri "mia vivo ne estas libera... mia vivo ne estas mallibera."

Comment: Vi pravas, la demando estas preskaŭ la sama demando.